# How do I find the center of mass of a region given by a function using integration

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, physics, wolframalpha

So I'm currently working on a project where i want to find the center of mass of a given region. To be exact, i want to find the center of mass (using moments and all of that) of this region
[the plane i want to find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRL1Y.png)

Its a circle with a radius of 3 and is cut as you can see in the picture at x=5.3
How do i find the center of mass of such a plane (do i have to cut into seperate functions or do i have to use another equation please help

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that its a wolfram-mathematica related problem initially.

Getting the general idea from this page
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146618/center-of-mass-of-2d-region/146619
This is how you can solve.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= 5.3,(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2<=9, 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z}];
RegionCentroid[reg]//Most
```